# Cannot run spa-prerender in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppeteer, prerender

I'm trying to prerender some Vue.js application in Google Build (from GKP) using [prerender-spa-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-spa-plugin) and my build script run into an issue with starting headless Chrome browser using puppeteer.

It stands in documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-the-cloud) that `The Node.js runtime of the App Engine standard environment comes with all system packages needed to run Headless Chrome.` 
I'm getting error in console:

```
Step #2: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
Step #2: /workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-672088/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Step #2: 
Step #2: 
Step #2: TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

Everythink works fine in local environment.
I also tried to run simply script only running puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function startPuppeteer() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    });

    console.log('browser started!!!');
}


startPuppeteer();
```

and it also fails.

This is my cloudbuild.yml configuration

```
steps:
- name: node:8.14.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: node:8.14.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'prerender']
```

in `prerender` script i simply run webpack with prerender plugin enabled.
But the problem is with running puppeteer in Google Cloud so i won't attach any webpack configuration, i think it's pointless

Comment: Cloud Build uses a custom container for building. There are a variety to chose from. However, I am not aware of one that includes headless Chrome: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders You can build your own container for Cloud Build and include the tools you need.